# Azure App Service - Outbound IP addresses vs Additional Outbound IP Addresses

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Azure App Service has 2 types of outbound IP addresses:

1. Outbound IP Address:
2. Additional Outbound IP address:

I would like to know from the whitelisting perspective, which category do I need to use in my firewall?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, you should whiteliste the **Additional Outbound IP addresses**:

> An App Service app runs in an App Service plan, and App Service plans
> are deployed into one of the deployment units in the Azure
> infrastructure (internally called a webspace). Each deployment unit is
> assigned up to five virtual IP addresses, which includes one public
> inbound IP address and four outbound IP addresses. All App Service
> plans in the same deployment unit, and app instances that run in them,
> share the same set of virtual IP addresses. For an App Service
> Environment (an App Service plan in Isolated tier), the App Service
> plan is the deployment unit itself, so the virtual IP addresses are
> dedicated to it as a result.
>
> Because you're not allowed to move an App Service plan between
> deployment units, the virtual IP addresses assigned to your app
> usually remain the same, but there are exceptions.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips).

So for some exceptions like if you scale your app between tier, one or more of the four outbound IP addresses **may change** (with some of the additional outbound IP addresses)
See: [When outbound IPs change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips#when-outbound-ips-change)